# Command to make my bot leave a specific guild: discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a command to make the bot leave a specific guild. Usage would be -leave [guild]

I don't really know what to try out, but I've messed with some of the arguments a bit; did nothing

```py
@commands.command(hidden=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def leave(self, ctx, guild: discord.Guild):
    await self.bot.leave_guild(guild)
    await ctx.send(f":ok_hand: Left guild: {guild.name} ({guild.id})")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.converter' has no attribute 'GuildConverter'
```

I'd like the bot to leave the guild and send a confirmation message shown in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in converter for guilds, so you'll have to do it yourself:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def leave(self, ctx, *, guild_name):
    guild = discord.utils.get(self.bot.guilds, name=guild_name)
    if guild is None:
        await ctx.send("I don't recognize that guild.")
        return
    await self.bot.leave_guild(guild)
    await ctx.send(f":ok_hand: Left guild: {guild.name} ({guild.id})")
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find a different solution based on this answer:
`@commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def leave(self, ctx, *, guildinput):
        try:
            guildid = int(guildinput)
        except:
            await ctx.send("Invalid guild: failed to convert to int")
        try:
            guild = self.bot.get_guild(guildid)
        except:
            await ctx.send("Invalid guild")
        try:
            await guild.leave()
            await ctx.send(f"left {guild.name}")
        except:
            await ctx.send("Error leaving")`